# GWT getElement().setattribute("required","true") not working

Tags: html, validation, gwt

I have the following piece of code

```
   ** element.getElement().setPropertyString("placeholder","name");
    element.getElement().setAttribute("required", "true");**
```

I want to add a place holder and i don't want my field to be empty, the placeholder code works fine but the required attribute isn't working

Comment: Which element? What do you mean by "not working"? In a specific browser or in different browsers? You need to be more specific - otherwise it is very difficult for the community to help you find a solution.

Comment: the attribute **required ** is not working , i am working on chromium browser v31 with gwt plugin added

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Hope it will help

```
**.getElement().setPropertyBoolean("required", true);
```